# Image styles not generated on IIS

Tags: 7, media

I'm forced to build a site on IIS-based hosting. I have a problem with different image styles (thumbnails etc.) not being generated when uploading an image using image field on a node. The original image gets uploaded and works normally, but other styles don't. To clarify - Drupal gives me a permission error (not allowed to view this page), but the image also doesn't appear on the server, I checked via FTP.

I found [Image styles not generated with Drupal 7 on IIS 6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/image-styles-not-generated-with-drupal-7-on-iis-6) which seemed like a very similar issue, but provided solutions did not help.

Comment: Does the status report (/admin/reports/status) show anything wrong?

Comment: Nope. If you were thinking about filesystem issues, I believe there aren't any - especially since the original sized file gets uploaded normally.

Comment: I was getting a 404, not a 403, but the rest of the behavior you describe matches... I found having a trailing / on my public file system path was causing image styles to not be rendered after upgrading to Drupal 7.20 and PHP 5.3